# Permanent carapace of conscience

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is meant by the emboldened part

> The pictures that the world sees of the latest outbreak are not pleasant and many in India are pained by what the TV channels are carrying daily into their bedrooms. ***Nationalism cannot be the permanent carapace of conscience.***

[[Indian Express](http://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/kashmir-situation-india-pakistan-indo-pak-war-bangladesh-un-the-bilateral-bind-3035013/)]

Comment: Nothing is underlined in your question. Underline is not supported by SE markup. Instead, please use bold text to set off the part of the sentence you are concerned with. Is it **permanent carapace of conscience**?

Comment: I am so so sorry. I just forgot emboldening it. My apologies. And yes, you are right, that is what I don't understand. Many thanks.

Comment: The journalist here is using a _metaphor_ to say _India cannot use nationalism to protect itself from its conscience._ Have you used a dictionary to learn what _carapace_ and _conscience_ mean in English?

Comment: In fairness to the OP, I don't think the metaphor is clear at all. I have no idea what it means for conscience to have a protective shell of nationalism.

Comment: That we do things that out conscience would normally find unacceptable, justifying them by nationalism. Our conscience doesn't "see" the actions because of nationalism.

Comment: @TRomano You're right of course; the metaphor is strained, but the first step in deciphering it is to know what a carapace and a conscience are. My hope was that, having learnt the meanings of those words, the OP would ponder the metaphor and have a _satori._

Comment: @P.E. Dant: Agreed, OP should have told  us what he knew about the word **carapace**.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze this by the key words.

> **Nationalism** cannot be the *permanent* **carapace** of **conscience**.

**Nationalism** is way of thinking and framing how you view the world; specifically, viewing your country as good, and more typically, as *always* good.

A **conscience** is your ability to discern right from wrong, and good from bad.

A **carapace** is a hard shell belonging to some animals, such as turtles, used for protection.  Metaphorically then, the word **carapace** can be used to describe any form of protection.

*Permanent* things do not change, and are absolute– it brings to mind superlatives such as "*always*," "*all the time*," "*forever*," and so forth.

Typically, someone using **nationalism** believes that their country is correct for doing whatever action it is doing, for no reason other than that it is their country.  Having a **conscience** usually means analyzing a complex situation using a complex moral code, which can be exhausting and painful to do.

As such, **nationalism** can protect you, as if it were a **carapace**, by *always* (*permanently*) ignoring the complex analysis and simply saying "we are right," "we are correct," "we are good" *all the time* and for *every situation*.

The sentence says that this process of not analyzing situations on their own merits, but simply concluding that you are good and moral without the analysis, is itself wrong, implying that this act of nationalism is immoral.

In context, it is saying that shielding viewers in India from painful images that would would hurt them by way of their conscience, is an act of nationalism, and as an act of nationalism, is immortal.

Answer (score -2):

Carapace is hard upper shell of tortoise, or sheild, 
Conscience meaning moral sense

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining how this relates to the overall meaning of the sentence. OP specifically asks about the meaning of the sentence, not these two particular words.